# Route group prefix not working in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I was trying to make a `group routing` with a `prefix` in Laravel 8. But when I tested it in `http://localhost/mysite/admin/test/`, it always throws `error 404`.

Here is the code in `web.php`:

```
Route::prefix('/admin', function() {
    Route::get('/test', [Admin\LoginController::class, 'index']);
});
```

I created a controller in `app/Http/Controller/Admin/` as the controller is inside `Admin` folder.

Here is the code in `LoginController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Please login";
    }
}
```

Can anybody show me what I am doing wrong to get it working?

Comment: does it work when you do `php artisan serve` and visit `http:://localhost:8080/admin/test`?

Comment: i don't use `php artisan serve`. other routes work except the group with prefix

Comment: I'm asking because if it works using `php artisan serve` but not normally it's a webserver configuration issue rather than a router issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to group the routes as stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes) like:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/test', function () {
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});
```

In your case it would be:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController;

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/test', [LoginController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Comment: can you suggest me the code in my case? because i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be 'admin' not '/admin'.
That slash makes it:

`http://localhost/mysite//admin/test`

=>

`http://localhost/admin/test`

You can check all your routes using: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: same thing. somehow i cannot find it in the route list

Comment: @Abaij does `php artisan cache:clear` help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this

   ```
   use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController; 

   Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::get('test', ['LoginController::class, index'])->name('test'); });
   ```